# Item position type shift from relative to static effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, effects

How is this effect named ? How is it implemented

You can see it on [this](http://www.thejtsite.com/projects/) page on the portofolio filter box.

I've seen it around for a year, it's an interesting pattern, it's so famous gmail now uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the JavaScript they use: [fixed.js](http://www.thejtsite.com/js/fixed.js)

Their css:

```
#rightFloat {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 205px;
}
#rightFloat.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

What is the name? I have no clue if it has a name :) I bet people call it 100 different things.

[Edit:] names I have heard : sticky scroll, contained sticky scroll, conditional sticky scroll, watermarked content.

Comment: And it is repeatedly doing the `$('#rightFloat')` query, which might be cached on the first call.

Comment: @katspaugh: It is the fn code of the page @Andrei asked about.

Comment: There should deffinetely be a name

Comment: Added names I have heard. I am sure there are more made up names.

Comment: As @katspaugh pointed out, their jQuery code is not the best and can be improved.